# How do I solve this deceleration problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

Question:

A car is traveling at 100km/hr, when the driver sees an accident 80 meters ahead. What constant deceleration is required to stop the car in time to avoid a pileup?

So far I have approached the question using a velocity equation:
$$V^2=V_o+2ax$$
I changed the $80$m to be $0.08$km, and I set $V^2=0$ because that's the speed that she should end with, and $V_o$ to $100$km/hr

$$a={V^2-V_o^2\over 2x}$$
$$a={-100km^2/hr^2\over 0.16km}$$
$$a=62,500km^2/hr^2$$
$${62,500km\over hr}\cdot{hr\over 3600sec}=17.36km/sec$$

I don't think it's possible for a car to stop that quickly, so I know it's the wrong answer. How do I solve this equation? Am I supposed to be using calculus?

Comment: Don't worry, your answer is right (you just have a few typos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you taught to use km/hr etc as units ?

If so, your final *units* are wrong, actually it is a hybrid (but may be **practically** useful) unit of -17.36 km/hr/s acceleration = 17.36 km/hr/s deceleration

However, we were always taught to use meters and seconds !

Speed = 100km/hr = $\frac{100\cdot1000}{3600} = \frac{250}{9}$ m/s

so using the SUVAT equation, **$v^2 = u^2 +2as$**,

0 = **$\left(\frac{250}{9}\right)^2 + 2\cdot80a$**

which yields a = $\approx$ -4.8225 m/$s^2$

Answer (score 1):

Your initial equation is wrong two ways, which you can tell from the units.  I don't know where you got it.  $V^2$ and $2ax$ have units $(m/sec)^2$, while $V_0$ has units $m/sec$.  The correct equation is $V(t)=V_0+at$.  For your problem, you will also need the distance equation at constant acceleration, which look like $s(t)=s_0+V_0t+\frac 12at^2$  You know that at the time the car stops $v(t)=0, s(t)=80m$  That gives two equations for the two unknowns $a,t$.  Watch the units

Answer (score 1):

Notice, the third equation of the motion $$v^2=u^2+2as$$ the car is being retarded hence, substituting the values, distance, $s=80\ m$, initial velocity, $u=100\  km/hr=100\times \frac{1000}{3600}=\frac{500}{18}\ m/sec$ & final velocity, $v=0$  as follows $$0=\left(\frac{500}{18}\right)^2+2a(80)$$ $$a=\frac{-250000}{324\times 160}=-\frac{3125}{648}\ m/sec^2$$ $$=-\frac{3125}{648}\times \frac{(3600)^2}{1000}=62500\ km/hr^2$$ Negative sign shows the retardation of the car. Thus in order to avoid accident the car must be retarded by $\frac{3125}{648}\approx 4.82253\ m/sec^2$ or $62500\ km/hr^2$.

Comment: This is the same that the OP did

Comment: Could you explain to me how you got the ${5\over 18}$x$100m/sec$? When I redid the equation and started with 100km/hr as 27.78m/sec I ended up with the same solution as you.

Comment: Alright, $1 km/hr=1\times \frac{1000}{3600}=\frac{5}{18} m/sec$